# How can I get multiple inputs from the user that are in a list to print while the program loops in Python?

Tags: python

1. I got the program to loop and to ask the user for input. The problem is...when I try to print it keeps giving me an error. I need it to be in a specific format. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
2. Here is the error:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\one\Desktop\Sherry\Python Folder\Week 4\w4_sgomez_assgn.py", line 40, in <module>
   print('\t-----' + employee[0:4] + '-----\n')
   TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
   ```
3. Here is the code:

   ```
   employee=[]
   count=0

   def addEmpl(employee, count):
     if count < 5:
      name=input('Enter Employee Name: ')
      ssn=input('Enter Employee SSN: ')
      phone=input('Enter Employee Phone: ')
      email=input('Enter Employee Email: ')
      salary=input('Enter Employee Salary: ')
      report = name +',' + ssn + ',' + phone +','+ email +',' + salary
      employee.insert(count,report)
      count=count+1

   def printEmpl(employee):
     number=int(input('Press 0 to print list: '))
     count = len(employee)
     if (number>-1) and (number<1):
      employee=employee[0]
      employee='\n'.join([name,ssn, phone, email, salary])
      employee[:]
      print('\t-----' + employee[0:4] + '-----\n')
      print('SSN: ' + employee[1] + '\n')
      print('Phone: ' + employee[2] + '\n')
      print('Email: ' + employee[3] + '\n')
      print('Salary: $' + employee[4] + '\n')
      print('\t-----------')
     else:
      return;    

   while True:
     addEmp2=int(input('To add employee enter 1; to print enter 2; to search by ssn enter 3: '))
     if (addEmp2 > 0)and(addEmp2 < 2):
      addEmpl(employee, count)
     else:
      print('\t-----' + employee[0:4] + '-----\n')
      print('SSN: ' + employee[1] + '\n')
      print('Phone: ' + employee[2] + '\n')
      print('Email: ' + employee[3] + '\n')
      print('Salary: $' + employee[4] + '\n')
      print('\t-----------')
   ```

Comment: Wow, the code is super-badly-formatted, it's equivalently worthless to not showing a code.

Comment: Please include the _complete_ error message.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the correct code for function addEmpl below

```
def addEmpl(employee, count):
  if count < 5:
   name=raw_input('Enter Employee Name: ')
   ssn=raw_input('Enter Employee SSN: ')
   phone=raw_input('Enter Employee Phone: ')
   email=raw_input('Enter Employee Email: ')
   salary=raw_input('Enter Employee Salary: ')
   report = name +',' + ssn + ',' + phone +','+ email +',' + salary
   employee.insert(count,report)
   count=count+1
```

Since, you have not given the complete error, so as per my best guess I tried to fix it. Please let me know if my understand is not correct.

Comment: I guess my question is...how do I call the function from the first user input? I want to print just the name...then...just the ssn...then just the phone...etc. Nothing I am doing seems to work.

Comment: If I print: employee[0], it prints the first employee with their info in the first name line instead of just the name. If I put their name it tells me the name is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The following line is triggering the error (it is in 2 places)

```
print('\t-----' + employee[0:4] + '-----\n')
```

You are using `+` operator on a string and list together `employee[0:4]` is a list.
Hence the error

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following line:

```
 print('\t-----' + employee[0:4] + '-----\n')
```

You can't print it as is you need to convert the list to a string.
Something like

```
string=""
for x in range(len(employee)):
    string=string+x
 print('\t-----' + string + '-----\n')
```

The real problem here though is the structure you should really be using a class for this instead of a list like so.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,name,ssn,phone,email,salary):
        self.name=name
        self.ssn=ssn
        self.phone=phone
        self.email=email
        self.salary=salary

empObj=Employee("RandomName",1231231,"444-777-8000","pretendEmail@somewhere.com",4000)
print(empObj.name)
```